# Prove measurability of a function defined from two measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

You have two measurable functions $L$ and $U$ defined on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],Leb)$. Define 
$$
f
=
\begin{cases}
L & \text{if }L=U \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The text says $f$ is *clearly* measurable. Its not so obvious to me. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ and $U$ are measurable, for is their difference $L-U$ and hence 
$$
E=(L-U)^{-1}(\{0\})
$$
is a measurable set, as an inverse of a measurable set. In particular, the characteristic functions of $E$ and $E^c$ are measurable functions.

So
$$
f=\chi_E\cdot L,
$$
and thus $f$ is measurable as a product of such.